What is the status of other intelligent magical beings in Harry Potter and the Cursed Child?
Hermione is a character very determined to help other intelligent magical beings like house elves obtain rights. She even created SPEW in her fourth year. In Harry Potter and the Cursed Child, she is the Minister of Magic.
Is there any evidence that the status (rights, social standing etc.) of other intelligent magical beings in Harry Potter and the Cursed Child has changed?
